# splitting pandas column containing list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column, with each cell in the column containing a list of dicts with color attributes of each photo, such as:

```
[{'color': 'black', 'confidence': 1.0}, {'color': 'brown', 'confidence': 0.72}, {'color': 'gray', 'confidence': 0.62}, {'color': 'other', 'confidence': 0.52}, {'color': 'red', 'confidence': 0.01}, {'color': 'blond', 'confidence': 0.01}, {'color': 'white', 'confidence': 0.0}]
```

I want to be able to split this column containing lists of dicts into multiple new pandas columns. For example, I want a column named "black", with the value "1.0", a column named "brown" with the value "0.72" ect.

I'm struggling to get this done. Will appreciate tips.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{'color': 'black', 'confidence': 1.0}, {'color': 'brown', 'confidence': 0.72}, {'color': 'gray', 'confidence': 0.62}, {'color': 'other', 'confidence': 0.52}, {'color': 'red', 'confidence': 0.01}, {'color': 'blond', 'confidence': 0.01}, {'color': 'white', 'confidence': 0.0}]

c= []
co = []
for d in a:
    c.append(d['color'])
    co.append(d['confidence'])
    
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['color'] = c
df['confidence'] = co

df = df.transpose()
#make the first column header
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

```
Output:
df
Out[159]: 
color      black brown  gray other   red blond white
confidence     1  0.72  0.62  0.52  0.01  0.01     0
'''

If this answer is correct, kindly accept and upvote the answer. Else, comment the doubt or issue, I would be happy to help
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col'].tolist()).set_index('color').T
```

Output:

```
color       black  brown  gray  other   red  blond  white
confidence    1.0   0.72  0.62   0.52  0.01   0.01    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all. This worked for me. I was inspired by Tejas answer:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df["black"]=""
df["brown"]=""
df["gray"]=""
df["other"]=""
df["red"]=""
df["blond"]=""
df["white"]=""

for k,v in df.iterrows():
    res = literal_eval(df["Color_list"][k])
    for d in res:
         df[d["color"]][k]=d["confidence"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function with `apply` that returns a `Series` to do this:

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["a", "b"],
        "B": [
            [
                {"color": "black", "confidence": 1.0},
                {"color": "brown", "confidence": 0.72},
                {"color": "gray", "confidence": 0.62},
                {"color": "other", "confidence": 0.52},
                {"color": "red", "confidence": 0.01},
                {"color": "blond", "confidence": 0.01},
                {"color": "white", "confidence": 0.0},
            ],
            [
                {"color": "black", "confidence": 0.8},
                {"color": "brown", "confidence": 0.5},
                {"color": "gray", "confidence": 0.4},
                {"color": "other", "confidence": 0.32},
                {"color": "red", "confidence": 0.11},
            ],
        ],
    }
)

print(df)
   A                                                  B
0  a  [{'color': 'black', 'confidence': 1.0}, {'colo...
1  b  [{'color': 'black', 'confidence': 0.8}, {'colo...
```

**Method**
Since each cell is a list of dictionaries, we need to turn each cell into its own `Series` where the index is the `"color"` and the values are the `"confidence"`. `apply` takes care of sticking these `Series` objects together and outputting a new `DataFrame`

```
def clean_cell(records, index, values):
    return (pd.DataFrame(records)
            .set_index(index)
            .rename_axis(None)
            [values])

record_df = df["B"].apply(clean_cell, args=("color", "confidence"))

print(record_df)
   black  brown  gray  other   red  blond  white
0    1.0   0.72  0.62   0.52  0.01   0.01    0.0
1    0.8   0.50  0.40   0.32  0.11    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: thanks, didn't get around to trying it, found different solution